# PHP https post XML data with cURL

Tags: php, post, curl, https

I'm trying to send a HTTPS POST request with XML data to a server using PHP.

Anything sends to the server requires authentication therefore I'll use cURL.

Some background info.: the XML data is to request the server to upload a file from a specific URL to its local storage.

One rule of using this API is I MUST set the content type for each request to **application/xml**.

This is what I've done but isn't working...

```
<?php
$fields = array(
'data'=>'<n1:asset xmlns:n1="http://.....com/"><title>AAAA</title><fileName>http://192.168.11.30:8080/xxx.html</fileName><description>AAAA_desc</description><fileType>HTML</fileType></n1:asset>'
);
$fields_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$url = "https://192.168.11.41:8443/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:12345678");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml', 'Content-length: '. strlen($fields_string)) );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close($ch); 

echo $result;
?>
```

I am expected to get an XML reply of either upload successful or upload failed.
But instead I am getting this error message.

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Length: 0 Date: Thu, 02 Dec
>   2010 03:02:33 GMT

I'm sure the file type is correct, the XML format is correct.
I've tried urlencode the fields but it didn't work.
What else I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solve with

```
$xml = $this->getXml();
$url = $this->getUrl();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                       'Content-type: application/xml', 
                                       'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml)
                                     ));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is the difference between curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); What does that tell CURL exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try text/xml instead of application/xml?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do, in you original code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields['data']);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '<n1:asset xmlns:n1="http://.....com/"><title>AAAA</title><fileName>http://192.168.11.30:8080/xxx.html</fileName><description>AAAA_desc</description><fileType>HTML</fileType></n1:asset>');
```

I mean that you have to send the XML directly.

Comment: just tried that, that didn't work. It replied with the same error message.